# How to insert javascript variable inside url?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, hyperlink

How can I insert a variable, `x`, inside a link, I tried using "," but I did not succeed:

```
function ChangeBackgroundImage(){
    var x = document.getElementById("backgroundimage").value;
    document.getElementById(clickedDivId).style.backgroundImage = "url(' + x + ')";
}
```

Comment: `...  = "url('" + x + "')"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the usages of the quotes:

```
function ChangeBackgroundImage(){
    var x = document.getElementById("backgroundimage").value;
    document.getElementById(clickedDivId).style.backgroundImage = "url('" + x + "')";
}
```

Comment: @Alireza, why did you also include my answer into yours, after I posted it? I specifically posted mine because yours didn't say anything about template literals and it's the default go-to solution for complex string compilation.

Comment: @maja Then it's likely there's something else wrong with your code. Can you update your question to also include the HTML?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I was thinking to add it to my post it later. But I've seen your answer and I appreciate it. I've deleted mine.

Answer (score 1):

Another popular approach to this problem is the use of a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```js
function ChangeBackgroundImage(){
    var x = document.getElementById("backgroundimage").value;
    document.getElementById(clickedDivId).style.backgroundImage = `url('${x}')`;
}
```

A template literal allows you to insert JavaScript expressions inside curly brackets prefixed by a dollar sign. Everything outside of the curly brackets is interpreted as a *literal* string.